# Finding the Last Non-Empty Cell in a Row With a Particular Set of Values

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

I have a spreadsheet of student data, where each row is a single student. For any given class, there are multiple columns 1-N, where N is the most number of times any of the students has repeated the course. So, some example data, where a course has been repeated at most 4 times, with what I want calculated in column E:

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |     E     |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 1 | 225-1 | 225-2 | 225-3 | 225-4 | 225-final |
| 2 | F     | EP    | C     |       | C         |
| 3 | A     |       |       |       | A         |
| 4 | W     | D     | W     | F     | F         |
| 5 | EP    | C     |       |       | C         |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

I've already discovered the `lookup` function, which seems to get me close to what I want. So, for example, `LOOKUP("X",A2:D2)` will get me the highest (i.e., latest in the alphabet) non-empty column for a given student. Given the data above, I would get output like the following:

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |     E     |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 1 | 225-1 | 225-2 | 225-3 | 225-4 | 225-final |
| 2 | F     | EP    | C     |       | F         |
| 3 | A     |       |       |       | A         |
| 4 | W     | D     | W     | F     | W         |
| 5 | EP    | C     |       |       | EP        |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Problems with this are as follows:

1. Rather than the highest non-empty column value, I actually want the lowest. So, students who earn a D, F, W, EP, or EF may grade replace the class, and will (hopefully) do better on a future attempt. I want to capture the most-recent attempt that isn't a W, EP, or EF (see below for those). Note that this is isn't always a better grade - we've had students get a D, grade replace, and then earn an F. I would want to capture the F.
2. One issue that complicates this is that students may receive a grade of EP or EF, which should not be included, and end up superseding the higher letter grades given my current approach, and would supersede an F if I could reverse `lookup` - these indicate that a student had an emergency withdrawal either passing or failing the course. I think I might replace all EP and EF values with WP or WF to simplify things. If me doing this affects your answer, please note that!

Comment: 1. I'm unfamiliar with W, EP, and EF as grades.  Can you clarify the grade "sequence" of worst to best (or do these grades actually mean something different that's outside the "good-better-best" continuum, like withdraw, and pass/fail)?  These three grades should be excluded from the selection?  2. You describe wanting the lowest letter (which equals the highest grade), but then describe wanting the higher letter if that was the result of the repeat.  Are you really after whatever is the last value in the row that is not W, EP, or EF?

Answer (score 1):

Going by your first matrix it seems you are interested in the last non-empty cell in that row. With the condition they must neither be equal to `EP`, `EF` nor `W`. Is this a correct assumption? If so, use below:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,,AGGREGATE(14,3,(A2:D2<>"")*(A2:D2<>"W")*(A2:D2<>"EP")*(A2:D2<>"EF")*(COLUMN(A2:D2)),1))
```

Drag down....

If this is not what you want, can you please tell me what the constraints are? At the moment, sometimes you explain the last value is what you are after, and in the end you state constraints.

**EDIT:**

How does this work?

[`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) will get the highest number (per the 14 parameter) returned from the equation `(A2:D2<>"")*(A2:D2<>"W")*(A2:D2<>"EP")*(A2:D2<>"EF")*(COLUMN(A2:D2)`, which will return an array of 1s and 0s based on all the specified rules, multiplied by their respective column number.  The highest column number result will be the qualifying value.

It will then use this largest number as the column parameter in the `INDEX` function.

Comment: JvdV: Thank you for your answer, it looks good. However- why are you adding an Excel tag to this? OP has tagged it with iwork-numbers, which would indicate this is what they are using. More generally, please try and be complete with edit suggestions- fix things like spelling, grammar or unclear phrasing. In particular, adding tags alone (eg "worksheet-function") is not always necessary and are more likely to be rejected by edit reviewers. I hope this helps you improve your edit suggestions, please do keep them coming :)

Comment: @bertieb, ahh right, thought it would be a relevant additional tag. Thanks for the feedback.